# bash shell doesn't replace $i

Tags: bash

I want to move files which list in the `file.idx` from `Scattered/` to `Selected`:

```
for (( i=1; i<100; i=i+1 ))
do
    mv "Scattered/$(sed '$i q;d' file.idx)" "Selected/"
done
```

But the bash shell doesn't replace `$i` from 1 to 100, and gives this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `i'
Scattered/ Selected/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sed command uses single quotes, so shell variables will not be expanded. Use double quotes instead:

```
mv "Scattered/$(sed "$i q;d" file.idx)" "Selected/"
```

As an aside, in your question you mention going from 1 to 100 but your loop currently ends at 99.

You can avoid using sed entirely by looping through your file in bash like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    mv "Scattered/$line" "Selected/"
done < file.idx
```

This approach is much more efficient that repeated calls to sed just to extract a line. If there are more than 100 lines in `file.idx`, you can always add an additional condition:

```
c=0
while read -r line && (( c++ < 100 )); do
    mv "Scattered/$line" "Selected/"
done < file.idx
```